# solving coupled differential equations with a periodically changing constant in the function with python

Tags: python, differential-equations

I am solving a system of coupled differential equations, with one of the "constant" in the differential equations is actually a periodically changing value: first half of the period has the value of 1 and the rest of the period have the value of 0, and the period is 2pi.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import math
l=1    
lt=0
k=0.05
eps= 0.11
w= (1 - eps) 
w_0= (1 + eps)
u=(w_0/4*w)*(w**2+(k/2)**2)


def RungeKutta(t, jx, jy, jz, x, p, dt, djxdt, djydt, djzdt, dxdt, dpdt):
    
    a1 = dt * djxdt(t, jx, jy, jz, x, p)
    b1 = dt * djydt(t, jx, jy, jz, x, p)
    c1 = dt * djzdt(t, jx, jy, jz, x, p)
    d1 = dt * dxdt(t, jx, jy, jz, x, p)
    e1 = dt * dpdt(t, jx, jy, jz, x, p)
    
    
    a2 = dt * djxdt(t + 0.5 * dt,  jx + 0.5 * a1, jy + 0.5 * b1, jz + 0.5 * c1, x + 0.5 * d1, p + 0.5 * e1)
    b2 = dt * djydt(t + 0.5 * dt,  jx + 0.5 * a1, jy + 0.5 * b1, jz + 0.5 * c1, x + 0.5 * d1, p + 0.5 * e1)
    c2 = dt * djzdt(t0 + 0.5 * dt,  jx + 0.5 * a1, jy + 0.5 * b1, jz + 0.5 * c1, x + 0.5 * d1, p + 0.5 * e1)
    d2 = dt * dxdt(t0 + 0.5 * dt,  jx + 0.5 * a1, jy + 0.5 * b1, jz + 0.5 * c1, x + 0.5 * d1, p + 0.5 * e1)
    e2 = dt * dpdt(t0 + 0.5 * dt,  jx + 0.5 * a1, jy + 0.5 * b1, jz + 0.5 * c1, x + 0.5 * d1, p + 0.5 * e1)
        
    a3 = dt * djxdt(t + 0.5 * dt,  jx + 0.5 * a2, jy + 0.5 * b2, jz + 0.5 * c2, x + 0.5 * d2, p + 0.5 * e2)
    b3 = dt * djydt(t + 0.5 * dt,  jx + 0.5 * a2, jy + 0.5 * b2, jz + 0.5 * c2, x + 0.5 * d2, p + 0.5 * e2)
    c3 = dt * djzdt(t + 0.5 * dt,  jx + 0.5 * a2, jy + 0.5 * b2, jz + 0.5 * c2, x + 0.5 * d2, p + 0.5 * e2)
    d3 = dt * dxdt(t + 0.5 * dt,  jx + 0.5 * a2, jy + 0.5 * b2, jz + 0.5 * c2, x + 0.5 * d2, p + 0.5 * e2)
    e3 = dt * dpdt(t + 0.5 * dt,  jx + 0.5 * a2, jy + 0.5 * b2, jz + 0.5 * c2, x + 0.5 * d2, p + 0.5 * e2)

    a4 = dt * djxdt(t + dt, jx + a3, jy + b3, jz + c3, x + d3, p + e3)
    b4 = dt * djydt(t + dt, jx + a3, jy + b3, jz + c3, x + d3, p + e3)
    c4 = dt * djzdt(t + dt, jx + a3, jy + b3, jz + c3, x + d3, p + e3)
    d4 = dt * dxdt(t + dt, jx + a3, jy + b3, jz + c3, x + d3, p + e3)
    e4 = dt * dpdt(t + dt, jx + a3, jy + b3, jz + c3, x + d3, p + e3)
    
  
    t = t+dt
    jx = jx+(1/6)*(a1+2*a2+2*a3+a4)
    jy = jy+(1/6)*(b1+2*b2+2*b3+b4)
    jz = jz+(1/6)*(c1+2*c2+2*c3+c4)
    x = x+(1/6)*(d1+2*d2+2*d3+d4)
    p = p+(1/6)*(e1+2*e2+2*e3+e4)


    return  t, jx, jy, jz, x, p



def djxdt(t, jx, jy, jz, x, p): 
    return -w_0*jy
    
def djydt(t, jx, jy, jz, x, p): 
    return w_0*jx-2*lambda_t(t)*(math.sqrt(2*w))*x*jz
   
def djzdt(t, jx, jy, jz, x, p): 
    return 2*lambda_t(t)*(math.sqrt(2*w))*x*jy

def dxdt(t, jx, jy, jz, x, p): 
    return p-(k/2)*x

def dpdt(t, jx, jy, jz, x, p): 
    return -(w**2)*x-(k/2)*p-2*lambda_t(t)*(math.sqrt(2*w))*jx

def lambda_t(t):
    if math.fmod(t, 2*np.pi) > np.pi:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0


t0=0
jx0= 0.5*math.sqrt(1-u**2) 
jy0= 0
jz0= -0.5*u
x0= -math.sqrt(2*w*(1-u**2))/(w**2-(k**2)/4)
p0= -(k/2)*math.sqrt(2*w*(1-u**2))/(w**2-(k**2)/4)
dt=0.0001*2*np.pi
t_end=50

t_list = [t0]
jx_list = [jx0]
jy_list = [jy0]
jz_list = [jz0]
x_list = [x0]
p_list = [p0]

t_list2 = [t0]
jx_list2 = [jx0]

t = t0
jx=jx0
jy=jy0
jz=jx0
x=x0
p=p0

while t <= t_end:
        t, jx, jy, jz, x, p = RungeKutta(t, jx, jy, jz, x, p, dt, djxdt, djydt, djzdt, dxdt, dpdt)
    
        if (t%2*math.pi<0.000001 or t%2*math.pi>0.000001):
            t_list2.append(t)
            jx_list2.append(jx)
        
        t_list.append(t)
        jx_list.append(jx)
        jy_list.append(jy)
        jz_list.append(jz)
        x_list.append(x)
        p_list.append(p)

plt.plot(t_list, jx_list, label="Jx")
plt.plot(t_list, jy_list, label="Jy")
plt.plot(t_list, jz_list, label="Jz")

plt.legend(fontsize=15)
plt.show()

plt.scatter(t_list2, jx_list2)
plt.show()
```

I do not know why it always comes out the error of unindent does not match any outer indentation level.

Also I need to plot the point and value only when t is the multiple of 2pi. I tried the code for

```
  if (t%2*math.pi==0):
            t_list2.append(t)
            jx_list2.append(jx)
```

But the figure comes out with only a dot at t=0
How to fix this problem? Is my previous setting influencing this part?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: As posted the code leads to the following error: `NameError: name 'f' is not defined` in the function `model`, line 21.
Note that you have to provide  **reproducible** code to get help.

Comment: This is the problem that I am facing. This is just a trying for the including the changing variable into the code. I do not know how to fix this problem.

Comment: Use the available data structures to make the code shorter, more comprehensible. With the last change you went in the opposite direction, your question is now less comprehensible and the connection to the present answer is lost.

Answer (score 0):

There are several things wrong from a pure python perspective in this function

```
def l(f):
    if int(2*t)%2np.pi == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return -1
```

- The parameter `f` is not used in the function, instead an undeclared `t` appears.
- `2np.pi` should give an immediate syntactic error
- `int(2*t)%2*np.pi` is`(int(2*t)%2)*np.pi`, which is likely not the desired interpretation. Use `int((2*f)%(2*np.pi))`. You can also cancel the 2
- The lower value is `-1`, while in the description you have `0`.

---

- `model` is a system for 3 state components, your initial state has 5 components. That is not compatible.

---

- Repeating expressions should be assigned to a local variable to avoid redundant computation.

---

Please report a detailed error description, not just your summary of the observed error.

Comment: The problems that you mentioned is solved, thank you for pointing out. However now python shows the error after running the part for solving the differential equation, and that said unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'int' and 'function'. 

I wonder if that is due to that I cannot use another function when I am solving differential equation with odeint.

Comment: Such errors are usually quite correctly described and located. One of the factors is not a number, here a function that is probably missing arguments. // What is `f` in `model`?

Comment: The f is what defined in the previous section, Is this not the way the code run?

Comment: `f` is a local variable of the function `l`, it does not exist outside. If that does not produce the error that is reported in the comment under the question, then you are working with a contaminated workspace that has `f` defined as global variable from somewhere else, probably as some function. // You still have the problem of the order of operations.